# Regex Pattern Replace

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

So i wanted to replace the following

```
<duration>89</duration>
```

with
(Expected Result or at least Shoud become this:)

```
\n<duration>89</duration>
```

so basically replace every < with \n< in regex So i figured.

```
sed -e 's/<[^/]/\n</g'
```

Only problem it obviously outputs

```
\n<uration>89</duration>
```

Which brings me to my question. How can i tell regex to mach for a character which follows < (is not /) but stop it from replacing it so i can get my expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/<[^/]/\\n&/g' file
```

or

```
sed -e 's/<[^/]/\n&/g' file
```

> `&`: refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched

Comment: Nice. The `-E` option is more portable IMHO

Answer (score 1):

It can be nicely done with `awk`:

```
echo '<duration>89</duration>' | awk '1' RS='<' ORS='\n<'
```

- `RS='<' sets the input record separator to`<`
- `ORS='\n<' sets the output record separator to`\n<'
- `1` always evaluates to true. An true condition without an subsequent action specified tells awk to print the record.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<duration>89</duration>" | sed -E 's/<([^\/])/\\n<\1/g'
```

should do it.

**Sample Run**

```
$ echo "<duration>89</duration>
> <tag>Some Stuff</tag>"| sed -E 's/<([^\/])/\\n<\1/g'
\n<duration>89</duration>
\n<tag>Some Stuff</tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<duration>89</duration>' | awk '{sub(/<dur/,"\\n<dur")}1'
\n<duration>89</duration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is kind of correct with one small problem. `sed` replaces entire pattern, even any condition you have put. So, `[^/]` conditional statement also gets replaced. What you need is to preserve this part, hence you can try any of the following two statements:

```
sed -e 's/<\([^/]\)/\n<\1/g' file
```

or as pointed by Cyrus

```
sed -e 's/<[^/]/\n&/g' file
```

Cheers!